# Change representation of Superclass without field depending of Subclass object (__str__)

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

I am running a django app and have a setup like this:

```
ModelSuper(models.Model):
   class Meta:
     abstract = False

ModelSub1(ModelA):
   name = models.CharField(...)
   
   def __str__:
      return self.name

ModelSub2(ModelA)
   name = models.CharField(...)

   def __str__:
      return self.name



ModelForeign(models.Model):
   element = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)

    def __str__:
      return self.name
```

So `ModelForeign` has a FK to `ModelSuper`. What happens now is that when I create an instance of `ModelForeign` I can choose if it belongs either to `ModelSub1` or to `ModelSub2`. But the string representation is `ModelSuper Onject (3)` where (3) is the id.

Normally I can change this representation by overwriting the `__str__` method on the model, but since I do not have any fields on the Supermodel I can't return anything.

What I tried:

- I have already implemented the `__str__` method in the Submodels but that does not help.
- I wanted to make the Super model abstract. But this does not let me point FKs to the Supermodel, so I can't do this. My setup requires this FK
- I used a generic FK with django's ContentType framework. This is also not an option because it messes completely with my app and is also not recommended from an SQL perspective.

Also when I do API-calls I get `ModelSuper Onject (3)` back instead of a human-readable name.

Is there a way to do what I intend to do? Thanks in advance for help and hints. Very much appreciated!

EDIT1: What I tried thanks to Abdul's help:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = False

    TYPE_CHOICES = [('sub1', 'sub1'), ('sub2', 'sub2')]
    type_model = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.type_model == "sub1":
            return "sub1"
        elif self.type_model == "sub2":
            return "sub2"
        else:
            return "unkown"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not understanding how your foreign key works as model inheritance means the tables are separate. How about trying something like this:-

```
ModelA(models.Model):
   TYPE_CHOICES = [('Sub1', 'ModelSub1'), ('Sub2', 'ModelSub2')]
   model_type = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
   def __str__:
      # Return string representation using if-else

   class Meta:
     abstract = False

ModelSub1(ModelA):
   name = models.CharField(...)
   model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   
   def __str__:
      return self.name

ModelSub2(ModelA)
   name = models.CharField(...)
   model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def __str__:
      return self.name



ModelForeign(models.Model):
   element = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)

    def __str__:
      return self.name
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried what you suggested and added it to the question. Maybe to clarify: I never create instances of `ModelA`, but only of the `Submodels`. What I tried with your suggestion gives me `unknown`

Comment: Also, when I try to create a new instance of a submodel I then get `__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)`... Weird... Any idea why that could be?

Comment: With this solution you have to create instances of ModelA Along with the Submodels. You can simply add a few lines in the views to do this for you when the instances of the Submodels are made. Also to make the relation you need to point a foreign key / OnetoOnefield from the submodels to the ModelA

Comment: do you have null=True on the CharField for name? If so try returning self.name or 'unknown'

Comment: Thank you again. hmmm I don't think it's an option for me to create an instance of ModelA every time I create a submodel... And I can't return `self.name` on the Superclass because I don't have a name field. And on the subclasses I already return `self.name`